# this.activatedRoute.snapshot.component have weird value "e" [Angular2]

Tags: angular, typescript

Thanks for helping me.

My Objective is to have name of component to do my logic.

But it works fine at my local, whenever i push it to DEV env the result is not the same.
What happens with it ?

Here is my code:

```
....

export class HomeComponent{
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activePage = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.component;
    this.activePage = this.activePage.name;
    if('EndUserLandingPage' === this.activePage){
       //do some stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the problem: 
Localhost: this.activePage is 'EndUserLandingPage'
Dev env: this.activePage is 'e'

[image]

DEV env:
[image]

Plz help me. I really don't know where "e" come from?

Answer (score 0):

That comes from the fact that you minimize and uglify when you build your dev environment. All class and method names will be renamed to something very short to save space. Disable that to keep the full class name.

`ng build --build-optimizer=false`

You can also disable that in your `angular.json` in path `projects.MYNAME.architect.build.configurations.CONFNAME.optimization`.